# Group chat in gtalk for Android

Tags: android, google-talk

I am making gtalk Im using smack 3.2.1 API.
I am stuck with group chat implementation. 
here is my code for initiate a group chat:

```
conf = new MultiUserChat(connection, "room@groupchat.google.com");  // create object of multiserchat class

         try 
         {  // Create the room
            conf.create("room@groupchat.google.com");

            // Send an empty room configuration form which indicates that we want an instant room
            conf.sendConfigurationForm(new Form(Form.TYPE_SUBMIT));
         } 

         catch (XMPPException e) 
         {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error in create room: "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }

conf.invite("userid", "Invitation for group chat");
```

But I am getting error: Service not Available (503)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Room should be -- private-chat-

And there is no need to create room.

Simply join the room with users name and password. That will satishfy:

Code snippet:

```
String room = "private-chat-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
room = room + "@groupchat.google.com";
MultiUserChat muc = new MultiUserChat(cc, room);
    muc.join("username", "password");
    muc.invite("username", "hi");
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Hi Ashish, I am also using Smack Api for group chat , but that is not working like facebook or some other group chats. I would like to know one thing clearly. Is Smack API will supports group Chat in Android. @Ashish